# Integral of $R(R^2+y^2)^{-3/2}$ with respect to $y$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+y^2}\left(R^2+y^2\right)}dy$$

The indefinite integral seems to be $$\frac{-R}{\sqrt{R^2+y^2}}+C$$

$R$ is a constant

Comment: Did you try differentiating your answer to see if you get the integrand?

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I did that and I did get the integrand so I know that the indefinite integral at least is correct, but I still do not know how to find the definite integral.

Comment: Where did x come from?

Comment: Actually, you don't. If you apply the chain rule $\dfrac{d}{dy}\left[-\dfrac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+y^2}}\right] = \dfrac{Ry}{(R^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$. See Andre Nicolas' answer on how to integrate this correctly.

Comment: Isn't (R^2+y^2)^3/2 = (R^2+y^2)(R^2+y^2)^1/2

Comment: Yes, but $\frac{Ry}{(R^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \neq \frac{R}{(R^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that $R$ is positive.

Let $y=R\tan\theta$ or equivalently $\theta=\arctan(y/R)$.  As $y$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$, the number $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Note that $\sqrt{R^2+y^2}\left(R^2+y^2\right)= R^3 \sec^3\theta$ and $dy=R\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$. We leave the rest to you.

Comment: If after completing the calculation you have some uncertainty, please leave a message.

Answer (score 2):

Using $y=Rx$, then $x=\tan(\theta)$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+y^2}\left(R^2+y^2\right)}\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac1R\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(1+x^2\right)}\\
&=\frac1R\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac1R
\end{align}
$$
It seems that you have miscomputed the primitive.

---

**Computing the Primitive**

Combining the previous substitutions with $y=R\tan(\theta)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+y^2}\left(R^2+y^2\right)}\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac1R\int\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac1R\sin(\theta)+C\\
&=\frac1R\frac{y}{\sqrt{R^2+y^2}}+C
\end{align}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{R \over \pars{R^{2} + y^{2}}^{3/2}}\,\dd y}}
^{\ds{y = \verts{R}\sinh\pars{\theta}}}\ =\
{R \over \verts{R}^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sech^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
=\left.{1 \over R}\,\tanh\pars{\theta}
\,\right\vert_{\,\theta\ =\ 0}^{\,\theta\ \to\ \infty}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over R}}
\end{align}