# Integral of $1/[(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I try to get back on track with the integration. I would like to solve

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

There are my way to try to solve it (that I don't find the right solution) and an other way proposed in the book that I don't understand :

Answer : $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

1. My way :
   $$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}}dx $$
   With the substitution : $t = 1+x^2$
   $$ \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}dt = \int_1^2 2tt^{-3/2}dt = 2\int_1^2 t^{-1/2}dt = 4\sqrt{t}|^2_1 = 4\sqrt{2}-3$$ which is wrong.
   I don't know if I did something that I wasn't allowed.
2. Book's way.
   With the substitution : $x = \tan(t)$
   $$ \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1+\tan^2(t)}{(1+\tan^2(t))\sqrt{1+\tan^2(t)}}dt = \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos(t) dt = \sin(t)|^{\pi/4}_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
   How did they find that was equal to $\cos(t)$ ? How did they find that would be a good idea to substitute with $\tan$ ?

Comment: $$t=1+x^2 \Rightarrow dt = 2x \,dx$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}dt \neq \int_1^2 2tt^{-3/2}dt$$

Comment: Oh, so I totally inverted ? To keep this example, I should use $$t=x+\frac{x^3}{3}$$ and then $$dt=1+x^2$$? (I know this is stupid, just for the example)

Comment: you're missing a $dx$ in your last expression, but I think you got the idea.
$$t=x+\frac{x^3}{3} \Rightarrow dt = \left( 1+x^2 \right)dx \Rightarrow dx = \frac{dt}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Ok perfect ! Now it rings a bell

Comment: This seems related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/898770). I derive the primitive, $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/898791), which for some reason was downvoted, so beware ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}.$$

If you then had the presence of mind to substitute $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, you would notice that

$$\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}},$$

and thus,

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

These are some kind of standard trigonometric substitutions:
$$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\text{ or }x^2-a^2\tag{$x=a\sin\theta$ or $x=a\cos\theta$}$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\text{ or }x^2+a^2\tag{$x=a\tan\theta$ or $x=a\cot\theta$}$$

Comment: @XogoX sorry i just posted incomplete answer accidently, see now

Answer (score 1):

1.If $t=1+x^2$ then $dt=2xdx $not $dx=2tdt$
2.A very useful rule of thumb is to substitute $x=tan t$ when you see $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ or $1/(1+x^2)$ to use $1+tan^2t=sec^2t$.Similar tricks include using x=sin/cos for $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ like terms and x=sec/csc for $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ like terms.

Comment: Is there a list of rules of thumb that I can found for the integration ?

Comment: try [Integration tips](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~taushean/download/tips-integration)

Answer (score 1):

By using the trigonometric substitution $x=\tan(t)$, we can see how the integrand simplifies to $\cos(t)$
\[
\frac{(1+\tan^{2}(t))}{(1+\tan^{2}(t))\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}(t)}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}(t)}}=\cos(t)
\]
I hope this helps you understand.

Comment: (+1) since this is essentially how I evaluated the primitive in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/898791).

Answer (score 1):

However, this integral doesn't need more attention; you could also use the substitution to solve the indefinite associated integral:

$$1+x^2=t^2x^2$$

And soyou'll find the integral as $$\int(-1/t^2)dt$$